# Group Dataframe Column Graph Based on Common x Axis Values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks at local maximums of Mass from 2001 to 2015. A section of it looks like:

[image]

I'm using the below to plot the dataframe as a graph. However, each tick mark displays the year, which looks congested on the plot.

```
df.plot(kind='bar', color='xkcd:grassy green', title=title, y='Max Mass (kg/m)', x='year')
```

Is there a way to have the 2001 columns grouped under a single '2001' group, and so on with 2002 - 2015 values. Looking for something that looks like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: can you do something like `df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x:x['Max Mass (kg/m)']).unstack().plot.bar(legend=False)`

Comment: @Chris I ran that code and got a graph and it seems that it's on the right track (let me know if there's a way I can show you). I haven't learnt 'lambda' expressions so I'm not sure how your code is working, is there a way to use something like

`df.groupby(['year']).apply(lambda x:x['Max Mass (kg/m)']).unstack().plot(kind=kind, color='xkcd:grassy green', title=title, y='Max Mass (kg/m)', x='year')`

so that I have more control of the graph format? I get a KeyError due to 'year' for some reason.

Comment: @Chris nevermind above comment, your approach is valid and works great!
I have noticed that the columns are shifted and not in center from the tick label. Any idea why? Increasing the width of the columns only stretches the columns further from the label.

Comment: I just created a quick example to test and you are correct. It looks like it is because of level 1 of mulitindex before `unstack` Let me see if I can fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should fix the problem...assuming that each group of year has the same length. IF not then you may need to subplot each group.

```
# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002], 'mass':[1,2,3,4,1,3,2,4]})

# create a multiindex from the cumcount of each year group
df['idx'] = df.groupby('year').cumcount()
df.set_index(['year', 'idx'], inplace=True)

# unstack and plot
df.unstack().plot.bar(legend=False, color='xkcd:grassy green', title='TITLE')
```

[image]